# Access the main window control from a usercontrol control's relay command

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, relaycommand

I have `MainWindow.xaml` with a `usercontrol` (`ButtonClusterUserControl.xaml`) and a `TextBlock` control.

The `usercontrol` itself has 2 `buttons`: `Hide` and `Show`. Requirement is something like

- when the `Hide` button is clicked, it should `hide` the `TextBlock`
  control.
- when the `Show` button is clicked, it should `display` the
  `TextBlock` control.

NOTE: This is not a real scenario. I have chosen this for illustration purpose.

Mock image for illustration:

[image]

What is the right procedure (with regard to loose coupling and separation of concern) to achieve this.

Comment: You have a right tag: add dependency property to a user control. Then it can be used to bind visibility of another control directly in `MainWindow`. That `propdp` (snippet to insert dependency property) has to be changed in buttons commands. What is hard? Where do you stuck?

Comment: Bind the buttons to a command that toggles a `bool` property of the view model. Then bind the `Visibility` property of the `TextBox` to this `bool` property using a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`.